# Gimp batch processing on the Mac?

Tags: batch, macros, gimp

I am looking for a way to batch apply auto-brightness, auto-contrast, and a dash of colour correction to a pile of images with Gimp.
I found a the David's Batch Processor (DBP) plugin but can't compile it on my Mac running Mac OS X 10.6.

1. Is there another way to achieve my goals?
2. If (DBP) is the way to go, how do I get it working in the Mac version of Gimp?

Thanks!